# iOS App - Support multiple language layout

Tags: ios, user-interface, multilingual

I want to build an iOS app which deals with multiple language like English and Hebrew. 
The user can change the language from app setting, and the UI should be updated from LTR or RTL depending on language (not depend on the device language).

I researched this quite a bit, but aside of the following solution, it seems like it's not possible:
Maintains two storyboards (one for each direction) - which can be painful.

Any other ideas \ solutions ?

P.S: 
I'm using leading and trailing constraints. 
In Android I can change the local and the UI is updated from LTR or RTL.

Answer (score 2):

if your are developing for an application for IOS >= 9 you can use this method for any control `setSemanticContentAttribute` and you can pass

```
  UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight
  UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft
```

for example

```
 [pageControl setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Yep... it's truly help. Any other solution for iOS 8.X ?